# Flutter: passing future<int> as int to Charts

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

I am making a mood checker application using flutter where user chose one of 5 emojis to tell their mood. 
I want to display a PieChart with data emoji vs num of Days it has been chosen.
Problem is that I have to fetch data from sqflite Database to get numOfDays a particular emoji is chosen which will be of type Future but charts can't take Futures, I tried to use async-await but it didn't seem to work.

**Error**

```
E/flutter (27721): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'
E/flutter (27721): #0      _MoodChartState.initData (package:pro_app/journal/view/mood_chart.dart:36:24)
E/flutter (27721): #1      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:49:6)
E/flutter (27721): #2      _MoodChartState.initData (package:pro_app/journal/view/mood_chart.dart:31:16)
E/flutter (27721): #3      _MoodChartState.initState (package:pro_app/journal/view/mood_chart.dart:58:5)
E/flutter (27721): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:58)
E/flutter (27721): #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3711:5)
E/flutter (27721): #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2956:14)
E/flutter (27721): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2759:12)
E/flutter (27721): #8      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (27721): #9      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (27721): #10     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3796:5)
E/flutter (27721): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (27721): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (27721): #14     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
E/flutter (27721): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #16     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (27721): #17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (27721): #18     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
E/flutter (27721): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #20     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:32)
E/flutter (27721): #21     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:17)
E/flutter (27721): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (27721): #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (27721): #25     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
E/flutter (27721): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (27721): #28     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (27721): #29     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4006:5)
E/flutter (27721): #30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #31     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (27721): #32     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (27721): #33     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
E/flutter (27721): #34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #35     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
E/flutter (27721): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (27721): #38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (27721): #39     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3796:5)
E/flutter (27721): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #41     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:14)
E/flutter (27721): #42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2748:15)
E/flutter (27721): #43     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3747:16)
E/flutter (27721): #44     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3559:5)
E/flutter (27721): #45     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3894:5)
E/flutter (27721): #46     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/wid
```

**Mood Model file**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class Mood {
  int _moodID;
  int _emojiID;
  int _actID;
  int _moodDay;
  int _moodMonth;
  int _moodYear;

  Mood(this._emojiID, this._moodDay, this._moodMonth, this._moodYear,
      this._actID);

  Mood.withId(this._moodID, this._emojiID, this._moodDay, this._moodMonth,
      this._moodYear, this._actID);

  int get moodID => _moodID;
  int get emojiID => _emojiID;
  int get actID => _actID;
  int get moodDay => _moodDay;
  int get moodMonth => _moodMonth;
  int get moodYear => _moodYear;

// can define setters as well

  Map<String, int> toMap() {
    var map = Map<String, int>();
    if (_moodID != null) {
      map['moodId'] = _moodID;
    }
    map['emojiId'] = _emojiID;
    map['actId'] = _actID;
    map['moodDay'] = _moodDay;
    map['moodMonth'] = _moodMonth;
    map['moodYear'] = _moodYear;
    return map;
  }

  Mood.fromMap(Map<String, int> map) {
    this._moodID = map['moodId'];
    this._emojiID = map['emojiId'];
    this._actID = map['actId'];
    this._moodDay = map['moodMap'];
    this._moodMonth = map['moodMonth'];
    this._moodYear = map['moodYear'];
  }
}
```

***Database file**

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import '../models/mood_model.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = new DatabaseHelper.internal();
  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

  final String tableName = "moodTable";
  final String colMoodId = "moodId";
  final String colEmojiId = "emojiId";
  final String colActId = "actId";
  final String colMoodDay = "moodDay";
  final String colMoodMonth = "moodMonth";
  final String colMoodYear = "moodYear";

  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db == null) {
      return initDb();
    }
    return _db;
  }

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  Future<Database> initDb() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "mood.db");
    var ourDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return ourDb;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE moodTable (moodId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, emojiId INTEGER, actId INTEGER, moodDay INTEGER, moodMonth INTEGER, moodYear INTEGER)");
    print("Table Created");
  }

  // insert
  Future<int> saveMood(Mood mood) async {  
    var dbClient = await this.db;
    int result = await dbClient.insert("$tableName", mood.toMap());
    print('Saved');
    return result;

  }



  // to get number of mood days
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> listOfMoods() async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.query(tableName, orderBy: '$colMoodId ASC');
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> numOfMoodDays(int emojiID) async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.query(tableName,
        orderBy: '$colMoodId ASC',
        where: '$colEmojiId = ?',
        whereArgs: [emojiID]);
    return result.length;
  }

  // close db
  Future close() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

**Mood_Chart file snippet**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
    import '../view/mood.dart';
    import '../models/mood_db.dart';
    import 'dart:async';

    class Mood {
      String _emoji;
      int _numOfDays; // this has to int bcz charts can't take future<int>
      charts.Color _color;

      Mood(this._emoji, this._numOfDays, this._color);
    }

    class MoodChart extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MoodChartState createState() => _MoodChartState();
    }

    class _MoodChartState extends State<MoodChart> {
      DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
      List<Mood> _data;
      List<charts.Series<Mood, String>> _chartData;

      // Here I used async-await but this function still return Future<int>    
      numOfDaysFn(int id) async {
        int numOfDays =await _databaseHelper.numOfMoodDays(id);
        return numOfDays;
      }

      void initData() async {
        _chartData = List<charts.Series<Mood, String>>();

        _data = <Mood>[
          Mood(
              allMoods[0], numOfDaysFn(1), charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault),
          Mood(allMoods[1], numOfDaysFn(2),
              charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault),
          Mood(allMoods[2], numOfDaysFn(3),
              charts.MaterialPalette.gray.shadeDefault),
          Mood(allMoods[3], numOfDaysFn(4),
              charts.MaterialPalette.indigo.shadeDefault),
          Mood(allMoods[4], numOfDaysFn(5),
              charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault),
        ];
        _chartData.add(charts.Series(
          id: 'Mood',
          data: _data,
          colorFn: (Mood mood, _) => mood._color,
          domainFn: (Mood mood, _) => mood._emoji,
          measureFn: (Mood mood, _) => **mood._numOfDays**, //this can't take futures
        ));
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initData();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: charts.PieChart(
            _chartData,
            animate: true,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
List allMoods = ['Disgusting', 'Bad', 'Ok', 'Good', 'Amazing'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this code runs because your sample code is not complete.
You kinda need to learn how dart futures work. When you call it, the result will return later like Javascript promises

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import '../view/mood.dart';
import '../models/mood_db.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Mood {
  String _emoji;
  int _numOfDays; // this has to int bcz charts can't take future<int>
  charts.Color _color;

  Mood(this._emoji, this._numOfDays, this._color);
}

class MoodChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MoodChartState createState() => _MoodChartState();
}

class _MoodChartState extends State<MoodChart> {
  DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  List<Mood> _data;
  List<charts.Series<Mood, String>> _chartData = null;

  // Here I used async-await but this function still return Future<int>    
  Future<List<int>> numOfDaysFn(List<int> days) async {
    return Future.wait(days.map((d) => _databaseHelper.numOfMoodDays(d)));
  }

  void initData( List<int> idx, List<int> days) {
    setState(() {


      _chartData = List<charts.Series<Mood, String>>();

      _data = <Mood>[
        Mood(
            allMoods[idx[0]-1], days[0], charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault),
        Mood(allMoods[idx[1]-1], days[1],
            charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault),
        Mood(allMoods[idx[2]-1], days[2],
            charts.MaterialPalette.gray.shadeDefault),
        Mood(allMoods[idx[3]-1], days[3],
            charts.MaterialPalette.indigo.shadeDefault),
        Mood(allMoods[idx[4]-1], days[4],
            charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault),
      ];
      _chartData.add(charts.Series(
        id: 'Mood',
        data: _data,
        colorFn: (Mood mood, _) => mood._color,
        domainFn: (Mood mood, _) => mood._emoji,
        measureFn: (Mood mood, _) => mood._numOfDays, //this can't take futures
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var months = [1,2,3,4,5];
    numOfDaysFn(months).then((days) {
        initData(months, days);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     if(_chartData != null ){
      return Container(
        child: charts.PieChart(
          _chartData,
          animate: true,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }
}
```

Revision 1

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import '../view/mood.dart';
import '../models/mood_db.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Mood {
  String _emoji;
  int _numOfDays; // this has to int bcz charts can't take future<int>
  charts.Color _color;

  Mood(this._emoji, this._numOfDays, this._color);
}

class MoodChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MoodChartState createState() => _MoodChartState();
}

class _MoodChartState extends State<MoodChart> {
  DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  List<Mood> _data;
  List<charts.Series<Mood, String>> _chartData = null;

  static List<charts.Color> DEFAULT_SHADE  = [
    null,
    charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault, 
    charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault, 
    charts.MaterialPalette.gray.shadeDefault,
    charts.MaterialPalette.indigo.shadeDefault,
    charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault];

  Future<Mood> numOfDaysFn(int day) async {
    return Mood(  allMood[day-1] , _databaseHelper.numOfMoodDays(day), DEFAULT_SHADE[day] );
  }
  Future<List<Mood>> returnAllNumOfDaysFn( List<int> days) async {
    return Future.wait(days.map((d) => numOfDaysFn(d)));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var months = [1,2,3,4,5];
    returnAllNumOfDaysFn(months).then((moods) {
      var temp = charts.Series(
        id: 'Mood',
        data: _data,
        colorFn: (Mood mood, _) => mood._color,
        domainFn: (Mood mood, _) => mood._emoji,
        measureFn: (Mood mood, _) => mood._numOfDays, //this can't take futures
      );
      setState(() {
        _data = moods;
        _chartData = temp;
      });

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     if(_chartData != null ){
      return Container(
        child: charts.PieChart(
          _chartData,
          animate: true,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#calling-multiple-funcs

Edit: you need to understand setState too

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Flutter charts provide sample with static data. However, you are fetching data dynamically so you need to call set state.

Comment: thank you from bottom of my heart for giving your time, yup the error is gone, but there is still one problem left, when I changed to some other screen of my app and then navigate back to chart screen, I see circularprogressIndicator() moving forever unless I hot reload the app which then displays the chart again.

Comment: I realize I mess up my bug. I forgot to write setState

Comment: I should change the code a bit. I just added set state but I should revise it even farther. You are not support to do lots of logic with setState. You are only suppose to change one variable

Comment: I made a quick and dirty change for now

Comment: I added a small revision. Try to make setState transparent and try to not make the fuction too big. Ideally, all you do for setState is assign a variable. Please look at the revision to understand

Comment: Yup, I too was thinking of making functions to assign value, thanks really appreciated.

Comment: Bro can you please answer this too  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55015019/flutter-pie-chart-labelaccessorfn-is-not-working  same code just I can't show lable on our pie chart