# how to call dart package method from Flutter app

Tags: class, methods, dart, flutter, package

I am trying to create a dart package and use it in my few flutter projects. The package is not public it’s a private package. I am trying to understand how to create a package with  working on an example. The documentation wasn’t so difficult, but it confuses me, because I am new to this type project.

So, I create private dart package project. My package name is socket_conn. The socket_conn.dart has single export line as export 'src/socket_conn_base.dart'; My socket_conn_base.dart has 1 class and 1 Future method.

My intention is to import this package to my flutter app, send data to EncrptedSocketCommunication and wait EncrptedSocketCommunication returns data from getQuery. It didn’t work.

I am not sure if I am doing right but calling EncrptedSocketCommunication how do I fire getQuery method, so it goes another class under my src folder (**getQueryA100**) and gets the data. The **getQueryA100** has a working and tested code. But when I import this package to my flutter app
İt doesn’t call  **Future>> getQuery**.

My question is how to call dart package method from Flutter app?

```
import 'csbins_socket/getQueryA100.dart';

List<List<dynamic>> _returnData;

class EncrptedSocketCommunication {

   String connectionText;
   String queryText;
   String parameterText;

   EncrptedSocketCommunication(
       this.connectionText,
       this.queryText,
       this.parameterText
       );

   Future<List<List<dynamic>>> getQuery(String connectionText, String queryText, String parameterText) async {

     switch (queryText){
       case "QA100": {
         _returnData = await getQueryA100(queryText, parameterText);
         return _returnData;
       }
       break;

     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Do not use await with future return type. https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: Thanks this is the one correction, any other correction regarding to my question? Am I right path to create a private package? Or should make a more modification?

Comment: You question seems a bit incomplete. I look at your code and saw one error. I do not know the details of the package you are refering to. All I know is how to use futures 
One more error, you will need to use setState to load dynamic data
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

You obviously, did not post your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I am using just dart code and no flutter code. My flutter app will call this page as shown in my question, and mh flutter app sends 3 string to this package. The package will make a http call to server and return dynamic list. So where should I use setstate? Every time my flutter app will calk this page it will create a new http call. Am I missing the dispose?

Comment: You use set state with a then clause. Your problem is similar to one I answered today
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965567/flutter-passing-futureint-as-int-to-charts/54965697#54965697
My answer does not have any type of caching

Comment: I will look at it, thanks